# 500 error getting object from web service by AJAX in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I am having a problem making an AJAX request to a web service.

I am trying to connect to the web service and get back an object to fill an HTML form with its data for editing.

The AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "WebService.asmx/UpdateNewGroup",
    data: "{ id : '7'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var myData = JSON.parse(data.d); // data.d is a JSON formatted string, to turn it into a JSON object
        alert("s");
    }
});
```

And the web service:

```
[WebMethod]
public MeGroup UpdateNewGroup(String id)
{
    MeGroup group = new MeGroup();
    return group;
}
```

This is the error I get when I send a request:

```
500 (Internal Server Error)
```

The path of the web service is right, and I enabled POST and GET requests in the service's `web.config`.

What could I be missing?

**Edit:**

Here is the error message I found based on J0e3gan's comment:

> Only Web services with a [ScriptService] attribute on the class definition can be called from script.

Comment: As you are getting `500 (Internal Server Error)` it clearly suggest problem is on server side.

Comment: ok i know but what should i do ?

Comment: What do you see if you run a debug build of the service, set a breakpoint in the web method, and attach your debugger to it?  You should be able to get a full stack trace of the underlying exception.  Alternatively you may be able to find details of the 500 error in the server's Windows application event log.  Regardless,  we need more information about the underlying server error to help you.

Comment: Only Web services with a [ScriptService] attribute on the class definition can be called from script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the error details you shared in reply to my comment, add the [`ScriptService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute to your service class as follows:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://yournamespace/")]
[ScriptService]
public class Your service
{
    [WebMethod]
    public MeGroup UpdateNewGroup(String id)
    {
        MeGroup group = new MeGroup();
        return group;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx its work for me yes I should add [ScriptService]

Comment: @SamySammour: Happy to help.  Now you know how to get more relevant information when you encounter similar server-side errors.